# How to use make C program part call a .a library in JNI

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm new to JNI, I'm trying to call a c function in java.

The C program uses a .a library. However, in order to create the object file which used for generate the .so library.

I can't link the c pragram to the .a library. The command I used is

`gcc -I./toolkithdir/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/include/ -c -fPIC JNIFitnessPart.c -o JNIFitnessPart.o libtoolkit.a -lm`

, as the -c option is used, the libtoolkit.a will not be linked.

How can I call the c function in java and the c function can also use the .a library?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: That isn't a lib or link finishing statement. it just compiles the .c to a .o file. The `libtoolkit.a` and `-lm` are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gcc -shared JNIFitnessPart.o libtoolkit.a -lm \
    -o libJNIFitness.so -Wl,-soname,libJNIFitness.so
```

GCC can be (and should be) used a linker wrapper, so it can easily assemble your binary.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly, there is no '\' in the command, right?

Comment: @user1524111 no, it is just to mark that the line is continued